# How does IEnumerable .Min handle Nullable types?

Tags: c#

So, IEnumerable uses the IComparable interface to evaluation a call to .Min().  I'm having trouble finding whether or not the nullable types support this.  Assuming I have a list of int?, {null, 1, 2}.  Will .Min() work?

Comment: Why not type it in to find out. But first agree with yourself what the outcome should be.

Comment: You're looking for this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341201.aspx

Comment: You might find this interesting too: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/09/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-29-min-max.aspx

Comment: @jdv - because this is actually faster in many cases than constructing a test program and is likely to tell me what it *should* do.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, it works.

The value `null` is neither greater than nor less than any non-null value - at least for the built in types. So the null values will effectively be ignored in `Min` or `Max` calculation unless all the values are `null`.

Answer (score 11):

The [following program](http://ideone.com/YcKhU)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<int?> l = new List<int?>() {1, null, 2};
        Console.WriteLine(l.Min());
    }
}
```

outputs 1. If the list is however [empty, or contains only `null`](http://ideone.com/G6BLr), the output is `null`.

So `null` counts as the biggest `int` for `Min`.

Answer (score 0):

The null values are ignored:

```
static void Main()
{
    var values = new int?[] { null, 1, 2 };
    Console.WriteLine(values.Min());
}
```

prints `1`.